# how to compare every element in array to a value

Tags: javascript

What I essantily want to do is compare all values in array to 123 in an if statment

```js
let values = [1, 2, 3, 123]
if (123 == values.forEach(e => {return e})){
```

currently, I'm getting an error:

> values.forEach(e => {return e})) is not a function

Comment: ForEach doesn't return a value. The comparison needs to be done inside the callback. P.s. don't abbreviate or paraphrase errors when posting...always paste the error in full, and mention the line it occurs on if its not obvious

Comment: Please explain and paste your error in question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand that you want, try something like this

```
let values = [1, 2, 3, 123]

if (values.includes(123)) {
   *do some code*
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const array1 = [1,2,123,123];

array1.forEach(element => element === 123 && console.log(element));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **array.indexOf()** function to check whether 123 is present in the array or not :

```
let values = [1, 2, 3, 123]

    if (values.indexOf(123)!=-1) {
       ...write code    
    }
```

```js
let values = [1, 2, 3, 123]

if (values.indexOf(123)!=-1) {
   console.log("123 is present");
}else {
  console.log("123 is not present");
}
```